# Reduce inside map inside map not efficient

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to run a series of keywords against a series of categories and then within those categories there are some options. So I have ended up doing a map over map over a reduce and when dealing with a lot of entries node consumes way too much memory.

I got this, what it does is not really the problem, but how to make it not crave for such amounts of memory?

```js
const keywords = [
  {
    Keyword: 'foo',
    URL: 'https://www.facebook.co.uk'
  },
  {
    Keyword: 'foo',
    URL: 'https://www.twitter.co.uk/blue'
  },
  {
    Keyword: 'faa',
    URL: 'https://www.facebook.co.uk/twitter'
  },
  {
    Keyword: 'faa',
    URL: 'https://www.apple.co.uk/green'
  }
]

const categories = [
  {
    name: 'Tech',
    options: [
      {
        method: 'include',
        regex: 'facebook'
      },
      {
        method: 'exclude',
        regex: 'twitter'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Green',
    options: [
      {
        method: 'include',
        regex: 'green'
      }
    ]
  }
]

const result = keywords.map((obj) => {
  categories.map(({ name, options }) => {
    const option = options.reduce((acc, { method, regex }) => {
      acc.push(method === 'include' ? obj.URL.includes(regex) : !obj.URL.includes(regex))
      return acc
    }, [])

    obj[name] = !option.includes(false)
  })

  return obj
})

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: If you can add some information about, how are you preparing to get the expected o/p?

Comment: I dont know what o/p means sorry

Comment: You don't use the result of the inner `map()`, so it should be `forEach()`.

Comment: @Álvaro o/p is short for output.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara The question says that the output is correct, the problem is that it uses too much memory producing it.

Comment: And since you're modifying `obj` in place, you're modifying the original `keywords` array, so there's no point in using `map()` there, either.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, but I am returning obj so I need map, are you suggesting using forEach on keywords too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating lots of arrays that aren't needed.

If you only care if `option` includes `false()`, you can replace the `reduce()` call with `every()`.

`categories.map()` should be `categories.forEach()`, since you don't use the resulting array.

Since you're modifying `obj` in place and returning this, the objects in the `result` array will be the same as in the `keywords` array, so there's no need to create a new array there, either. So you could use `forEach()` as well.

```js
const keywords = [{
    Keyword: 'foo',
    URL: 'https://www.facebook.co.uk'
  },
  {
    Keyword: 'foo',
    URL: 'https://www.twitter.co.uk/blue'
  },
  {
    Keyword: 'faa',
    URL: 'https://www.facebook.co.uk/twitter'
  },
  {
    Keyword: 'faa',
    URL: 'https://www.apple.co.uk/green'
  }
]

const categories = [{
    name: 'Tech',
    options: [{
        method: 'include',
        regex: 'facebook'
      },
      {
        method: 'exclude',
        regex: 'twitter'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Green',
    options: [{
      method: 'include',
      regex: 'green'
    }]
  }
]

keywords.forEach((obj) =>
  categories.forEach(({name, options}) => 
    obj[name] = options.every(({method, regex}) => 
      method === 'include' ? obj.URL.includes(regex) : !obj.URL.includes(regex))))

console.log(keywords)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but when dealing with 300K keywords I get CPU 99% and memory quite high too around 2GB

Comment: No matter what you do, it has to iterate #keywords x #options times, so it's doing lots of work. The only memory it's allocating is the added category properties in each keyword, that can't be avoided.

Comment: You could try changing the `forEach()` functions into `for` loops, that may be more efficient.

Comment: I actually had changed it to `for of`, well I guess it is what it is! Thanks!